# how retrieve errorBody with SpringWeb flux to fill a POJO out of exchange() method scope

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I’m busting my head with spring webflux comprehension.
I'd like, to retrieve the body error (String format)
to fill a pojo declared out of the scope of the webflux method.

How can we do that ?

```
ExtraScope extraScope = new ExtraScope;

Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<>();
vars.put("instrumentId", instrument);

RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = mdiWebclient
.get()
.uri(mdiEndpointsGetQuotations, vars)
.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

InstrumentDetailsDto block = request.exchangeToMono(r -> {
  if (r.statusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
      r.bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(errorBody -> {
          logger.debug("errorBody: [{}] ", errorBody);
          extraScope.setBody(errorBody);
      });
      return Mono.empty();
    }
  return r.bodyToMono(InstrumentDetailsDto.class);
})
.block(Duration.ofMinutes(5));

System.out.println("content of ExtraScope pojo: " + extraScope.getBody());
```

can you see in the else statement ?
how to do this ?

Comment: and what have you tried that doesnt work?

Comment: @Toerktumlare on the last line, content of ExtraScope pojo is null ! that's the issue.

Comment: Please update your code with what you have tried, instead of just leaving it blank and for us to write your code. We help people, i can help you through your problem but i wont write your implementation

Comment: @Toerktumlare code updated ! the logger display the errorBody into the exchange method. BUT, on the last line of the code, my extraScope pojo is empty !!